# How to write a basic back and forth dialogue in C++

Tags: c++, chatbot

I want to write a basic script that allows for back and forth communication between a user and the computer. For example

```
USER: what's your name?
BOT: my name is John
USER: what's today's weather?
BOT: the weather is sunny
```

The code I have so far is...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string respond(map<string, vector<string> > responses, string message) 
{
    if(responses.find(message) != responses.end()){
        return responses[message][0];
    } else {
        return responses["default"][0];
    }
}

int main(){
    map<string, vector<string> > responses;

    vector<string> temp;
    temp.push_back("my name is John");
    temp.push_back("they call me John");
    temp.push_back("I go by John");
    responses["what's your name?"] = temp;

    vector<string> temp1;
    temp1.push_back("the weather is sunny");
    temp1.push_back("it's cloudy today");
    responses["what's today's weather?"] = temp1;

    vector<string> temp2;
    temp2.push_back("default message");
    responses["default"] = temp2;

    while(1){
        cout << "Write your message to the bot and press ENTER" << 
 endl;
        string user_msg;
        cout << "USER: ";
        cin >> user_msg;
        if(user_msg == "quit"){
            break;
        }
        else{
            string temp = respond(responses, user_msg);
            cout << temp << endl;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Right now when I type in one of the `responses[]` (ie. `what's your name?`/`what's today's weather?`), I get back...

```
Write your message to the bot and press ENER
USER: what's your name?
default message
Write your message to the bot and press ENER
USER: default message
Write your message to the bot and press ENER
USER: default message
Write your message to the bot and press ENER
USER:
```

Any help to fix this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Off topic: `temp2.push_back("I don't understand you.");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the string correctly in your input. In the method `respond`, the value of `message` is just `what's`. This is happening because you are using `cin` which is not reading the input after it encounters a whitespace. You can use something like [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) instead.

```
cout << "USER: ";
// Do this
std::getline (std::cin, user_msg);
```

Here's a working example for your code: http://cpp.sh/5dnrh

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know how to get the program to display "BOT: " before the computer's response?

Comment: That's simple, define a `string` variable with the value `BOT: ` and concatenate it with the response when returning from `respond` method. Here's how you'd do it: http://cpp.sh/2e33k

Comment: @AkshayArora That's rather bad design because the BOT prefix is not part of the actual response. Prefer `std::cout << "BOT: " << temp << std::endl;`.

Comment: Prefer [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for documentation. cplusplus.com is less reliable because of not always being up to date.